# Как получить доступ к элементу View через его контекстное меню

Tags: android, view, android-menu, android-button, android-context-menu

Нажимаю на `Button5` длинным кликом. Выпадает контекстное меню (Переименовать, Удалить).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираю переименовать и вызывается например метод `editButton(button)` и меняет надпись на кнопке.
Так вот не могу понять, как мне получить `Button5` в  методе `public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button[] buttons = new Button[10];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createButtons();
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            registerForContextMenu(buttons[i]);
        }

    }

    public void createButtons() {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new Button(this);
            buttons[i].setId(i);
            buttons[i].setText("Button " + (i + 1));
            linearLayout.addView(buttons[i]);
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
         super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

         switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.edit:
                //Todo
                //Как здесь получить доступ к "Button5" на который нажали?????
                //edit(button); на который нажали длинным кликом
                break;
            case R.id.delete:
                break;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Класс `MenuItem` имеет метод [getActionView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getActionView())

Comment: пишу View view = item.getActionView() возвращает null почему-то. Не могли бы вы пример кода показать.

Comment: Да, `getActionView()` возвращает только `View`, установленное ранее методом `setActionView()`, здесь он не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать информацию, предоставляемую [AdapterContextMenuInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html):

```
View view = info.targetView;
```

При необходимости вы можете скастовать `View` к конкретному типу виджета:

Comment: info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();        переменная info == null; почему-то. Поэтому View view = info.targetView; не работает.

Comment: View v = findViewById(item.getItemId());  v == null; тоже. Следовательно не работает

Comment: @Денис7371 Я тоже не могу угадать, почему у вас `AdapterContextMenuInfo` - null, такого быть не должно и из представленного кода почему это происходит понять сложно.

Comment: @Денис7371 `AdapterContextMenuInfo` возвращает null потому, что метод `registerForContextMenu()` работает только со списком `ListView`. "Одиночные" `View` (как `Button`) он не обрабатывает. Соответственно вам нужно выводить свои кнопки через `ListView` или какие то костыли искать для обхода.

Comment: На [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html?hl=ru)написано:    "Зарегистрируйте класс View, с которым следует связать контекстное меню, вызвав метод registerForContextMenu() и передав ему View.    Если операция использует ListView или GridView и требуется, чтобы каждый элемент предоставлял одинаковое контекстное меню, зарегистрируйте все элементы для контекстного меню, передав ListView или GridView методу registerForContextMenu()."                 ....... Нигде не написано что registerForContextMenu() работает только со списком ListView

Comment: @Денис7371 Хорошо,  подробнее. `registerForContextMenu()` может работать с разными `View`. Только метод `getMenuInfo()` возвращает объект класса `AdapterContextMenuInfo`, в котором и хранится нужная вам информация, но чтобы извлечь из него эту информацию, метод `registerForContextMenu()` должен быть зарегестрирован на виджете, работающим с адаптером (таким, как `ListView`).  А в остальном ограничений нет. Как по другому получить `View` из меню (не через `AdapterContextMenuInfo`) я не знаю, но в любом случае это будет костыль. Проще вывести ваши кнопки через список, чем пытаться это обойти